# Residue of a function f

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

> $\int \dfrac{w^2}{(w^2+1)^2(w^2+2w+2)}=\dfrac{p \pi}{q}$, limits are from minus infinity to infinity.

Comment: Maple agrees with the locations of your poles.  It agrees on the residue at $1\pm i$. But disagrees on your residue at $\pm i$.  Once you have the residues, to find $p$ and $q$ you evaluate that integral using the residue theorem.  Of course you need to invent an appropriate contour to use.

Comment: Use Cauchy Residue Theorem to evaluate the integral which should give you a rational number $p/q$ where $p$ and $q$ are integers. Hence, you have $p$ and $q$. You need the residues which you calculated to use the CRT... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem Note, since the limits of the integral are $-\infty$ and $+\infty$ then you your path of integration will most likely be the half circle in the upper complex plane with infinite radius.

Comment: For $z=i$:$$\lim_{z\to  i}\frac{d}{dz}(z-i)^2\frac{z^2}{(z+i)^2(z-i)^2(z^2+2z+2)}$$

Comment: Ok. I found your answer.

Comment: Unless we are both wrong!!!

Comment: The residues now agree with Maple's output.  For $p$ and $q$.  This just shows it should be a rational number output.  What contour do you use?  How do you analyze the parts of the contour where it is supposed to go to zero?

Comment: $\int f=2\pi i\sum Residues$

Comment: You are quick. Do you use software?

Comment: Check your question. Isn't $\dfrac{p}{q}\pi$.?

Comment: No. the sum of residues is $\dfrac{7}{100}$. see $\dfrac{1}{-4i-3}=\dfrac{-3}{25}+\dfrac{4}{25}i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more comments see
\begin{eqnarray}
residue(f,-1+ i) &=& \dfrac{3}{25}-\dfrac{4}{25}i\\
residue(f,-1- i) &=& \dfrac{3}{25}+\dfrac{4}{25}i\\
residue(f, i) &=& -\dfrac{3}{25}+\frac{9 i}{100}\\
residue(f, -i) &=& -\dfrac{3}{25}-\frac{9 i}{100}
\end{eqnarray}
for integral $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^2(x^2+2x+2)}dx$ which lies in upper half plane, only residues in $i$ and $-1+i$ are important that concludes 
$$2\pi i\left(\dfrac{3}{25}-\dfrac{4}{25}i-\dfrac{3}{25}+\frac{9 i}{100}\right)=2\pi i\left(-\frac{7 i}{100}\right)=\dfrac{7}{50}\pi$$

Comment: Sorry, I didn't write more details. You'r welcome.

Comment: Sorry, which contour can I use in order to show that these residue's lie in that contour?

Comment: Upper-half circle $|z|<R$ (in upper half plane) that $R\to\infty$.